# Table of content and section formatting

Tags: table-of-contents, section-titles

I've managed to change the section formating mid-document. However, in the table of contents, the formatting resets. I'm new to latex so I don't fully understand the `\titleformat` option. I want it to say "Anexo A" but in the table of content it says "A  Anexo". 
Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Introdução}
    \blindtext

    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} 
    \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1\ \thesection}
    \section{Anexo}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess you have more than one appendix, otherwise simply using `\section*{Anexo A}` and a suitable `\addcontentsline` would be your easiest approach.  In the case of multiple appendices, you need to insert the change via `\addtocontents` at the same time you redefine the section format.  It's late and if I try to write an answer, I'll probably get it all wrong.  But look up `\addtocontents` and how to redefine the command for sections in the TOC.  (I don't know if it's provided in a package; it may require a patch.)

Answer (score 1):

You should simply switch `#1` and `\thesection`. The `#1` is the argument (i.e. the section title), whereas the `\thesection` is the value of the `section` counter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Introdução}
    \blindtext

    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}} 
    \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\thesection\ #1}

    \section{Anexo}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that does the opposite of what I want.
I want the `section` counter to appear after the section title in both the table of context and the document, "Anexo A". Where "Anexo" is the section title and "A" the section counter.